# Laravel - I can't call get config helper when I am in another Helper Class

Tags: laravel

Message:
Class 'Helpers\Config' not found

#### File:app/classes/Helpers/Helper.php

```
public static function getDictionary(){                    
$timezone = Config::get('app.dictionary');
```

#### File: config/app.php.

```
'aliasis => array(
'Helper'          => 'Helpers\Helper'
```

#### File: app/config/app.php

```
'dictionary'    =>  array(
'EMAIL'     =>  'crm@xxxx.com',
'VERSION'       => "1.0.0"
)
```

Is there any namespace or use line that I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're in a namespace in the `Helpers\Helper` file, when you refer to `Config` in that file PHP assumes you mean a class in the `Helpers\` namespace. You need to prefix it with a `\` to say you mean the 'root' `Config` class, or use a `use` statement:

1. Refer to it directly:

   ```
   $timezone = \Config::get('app.dictionary');
   ```
2. `use` it:

   ```
   use Config;

   class Helper
   {
        public static function getDictionary()
       {
           $timezone = Config::get('app.dictionary');
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```